# How to stop SBCL from buffering the input when reading a character?

Tags: buffer, common-lisp, sbcl

In the SBCL REPL, I ran `(read-char)`. Then, I entered a character (e.g. `A`). However, the `(read-char)` does not immediately return; it only returns when I press the enter key. SBCL seems to be buffering the input.

Is there a way to stop SBCL from buffering the input so that `(read-char)` does not require the user to press the enter key after entering a character?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need (force-output).

Comment: `(force-output)` is for flushing the output buffer, not the input buffer.

Comment: For example: (princ "Enter something: " query-io) (force-output) (setq abv (read)) <--- without query-io and (force-output) you'll end up seeing nothing until the very end (which is a long time if you have multiple input lines before the final output occurs), as OP is posting about. EDIT: query-io is surrounded by earmuffs. Not meant to italicize....)